# Anomaly in official video of the today's solar eclipse

Tags: the-sun, anomaly, video, eclipse

I watched an official nasa video of the solar eclipse that happened today.

https://t.me/uniannet/114510 - link to the news channel where the video was posted, not original.
At the fifteenth second of the video, an anomaly is clearly visible, which does not at all resemble a filming defect.
I have no idea how this could be explained.
Maybe someone else has it?

a few screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That absolutely looks like a digital filming defect. You see them all the time in pretty much any digital media.